# TFS - Some difference code projects for one Business Projects

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a question.

Lets say I have 3+ projects in TFS

For example

**Microservice A**

**Microservice B**

**Microservice C**

And now my company sign 2 contracts. With **Company ABC** and **Company ZYX**.

Now Project Manager want to open tasks for 2 projects  - **Company ABC** and **Company ZYX**.

But those tasks associated with **ALL MICROSERVICE** .
That is mean he is need to open tasks in each projects in **TFS**.

Question is:
If he able to see what is status of projects (where projects is project with  **Company ABC** and **Company ZYX**.)

P.S - Integration with **Project Server** is not good. Looking for something else (better inside **TFS** )

Comment: I don't understand the question. You should not create Team Projects for the customers. You can use branches to manage different versions of code. You can use areas or tags to manage work items for different customers. There are a lot of different ways to effectively manage this, but additional team projects are not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a task in every team project that has work to be done and use tags in tasks, user stories, etc to track for which customer it is for.

[image]

Create a custom cross project query to get all you workitems.
You could filter by tag or list all tasks and put the tag as a column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. This way work well (but think Microsoft have to think about something better, because with query information limited...) Any way thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not suggested use one team project for two companies. For enterprise-level organizations, it may be necessary to scale up, to create additional teams and/or team projects. These can be created within the single account or collection. Please check the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/scale-teams?view=vsts